# How do you convert this math equation to C++ statement?

Tags: c++

I would like to know how can I convert this equation to C++.

[image: math equation]

This is what I've tried.

```
void calPoints(int arti, int eksi, int hak) {

    int bir = 1, bin = 1000, on = 10, bes = 5;
    int puan = on * arti + bes * eksi + bir / hak * bin - arti * eksi / arti + eksi;

}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: puan won't be an integer in your equation so why take it as integer in your code?

Comment: I want to know how to do it right or know the right way.

Comment: You may want to study this: [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: You should use double (with what division by zero results with infinity) or if you are required to use int then you should avoid dividing by zero since it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Tiib "You should use double (with what division by zero results with infinity)" - What? That doesn't make any sense at all. The sentence doesn't parse as valid English. Any chance you could try and reword that?

Comment: @JesperJuhl i meant that when `STDC_IEC_559` is defined or `std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559()` is `true` (that is very common) then IEEE754 should be supported by compiler and so dividing double value by zero should not be treated as undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to be wary of when writing C++ code for this equation:  [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and integer math.

Operator precedence is easy enough to handle, and is only a concern for the last term.  The more interesting issues come from integer division.

The expression `1 / hak` will either be 0, 1, -1, or a divide-by-zero error, because the result of integer division is an integer.  `1 / 2` will be `0`.  The usual fix is to multiply first, then divide (as long as this ordering won't result in overflow).  In this case, we multiply by 1000 *first*, then divide.

Putting that all together gives:

```
int puan = on * arti + bes * eksi + bir * bin / hak - arti * eksi / (arti + eksi);
```

Although `bir` can be left out since it is `1`, and my personal inclination would be to leave the constants as constants in the equation, which makes it easier to verify:

```
int puan = 10 * arti + 5 * eksi + 1000 / hak - arti * eksi / (arti + eksi);
```

If integer based math is not desired, you'll need to change a few types to do things with floats or doubles.

```
double puan = 10.0 * arti + 5.0 * eksi + 1000.0 / hak - double(arti * eksi) / (arti + eksi);
```

In this form, all the constants are specified as double values, so that each term is evaluated as a double, with one cast in the last term to also calculate that as a double.  This result can be cast to an `int` if necessary.  The parameter types may need to be changed to `double`, depending on what values may need to be passed into the equation.

Comment: I was about to upvote, but this really needs to address doing the math with floating-point types, since that's almost certainly what's desired.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've added an explanation using doubles, although I've seen my share of equations where everything is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- arti * eksi / arti + eksi;
```

That's where your problem is. Think about the order of operations, it does multiplication and division before addition and subtraction.

Steps the code is taking:

1. arti * eksi
2. the result above / arti
3. the result above + eski

You need a parenthesis around the arti + eksi

Comment: That's not the only issue.

Comment: Öö Tiib is correct, you're using integers to compute a floating point result. Change your parameters and your result to doubles.

Answer (score -1):

```
double puan = (on * arti) + (bes * eski) + ((double)(bir/hak))*bin - (double)((arti*eski)/(arti+esi))
```

Puan is double because (bir/hak) and ((arti*eski)/(arti+esi)) might result in floating point number.
If you don't want it to be double then,

```
int puan = (on * arti) + (bes * eski) + (bir/hak)*bin - ((arti*eski)/(arti+esi))
```

This should work in your case. You should read about typecasting and precedence of arithmetic operators.

Comment: Way too many parentheses. If the constants are all defined as `double` or if the arguments are passed as `double` none of the casts are needed. The only essential parentheses are around `(arti + esi)`. The rest are just noise.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, you are right I just want to make it more clear to the OP. I know, but OP has taken them as int, hence typecast.

Comment: @TotallyNoob "but OP has taken them as int, hence typecast" - A *cast* is *rarely* the right solution (and often casts introduce bugs). In this case the arguments should probably be changed, to make a cast unneeded.